# C++ cannot open source file "hboost/predef/os/cygwin.h

Tags: c++, api, cygwin, houdini

I'm working with Houdini HDK (API), when I include
 `#include<OP/OP_OperatorTable.h>` or some other preprocessor i get the error message

the visual studio gives me this error, `C++ cannot open source file "hboost/predef/os/cygwin.h`

the full error message is:   `Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "hboost/predef/os/cygwin.h" NodeCreation    C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.5.467\toolkit\include\hboost\predef\os.h`

After I see this message for the first time I thought I should install Cygwin for windows, and I install the Cygwin but I get the error again

there's no cygwin.h file in this path, visual studio is searching for this file in this path
[image]
what's the problem and what should I do?

Comment: What is your IDE ? have you set up additional include directories in your project configuration section?

Comment: visual studio, no I didn't do that, how can I do that and where is the include directory for cygwin?

Comment: Where is installed your "hboost" ? Can you put full path please ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.5.467\toolkit\include\hboost

Comment: C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.5.467\toolkit\include\hboost\predef\os

Comment: there is no **cygwin.h** inside os folder

Comment: you say : I install the Cygwin but I get the error again ... you install the runtime version "for .exe" or developpement distribution "in wich you will have headers cygwin.h" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208697/discussion-between-landstalker-and-amin-khormaei).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont have `cygwin.h` that means you miss something when you install the `Houdini API`. I try a FULL installation by checking ALL the buttons below:

[image]

[image]

At the end, you will have this in your installation folder :

[image]

I am unable to tell you which one is responsible for installing "cygwin.h" but that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, but where is the include files , i updated the post with full error message

Comment: Proabably your `C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.5.467\toolkit\include\hboost\predef\os.h` try to do some thing like this : `#include "hboost/predef/os/cygwin.h"` BUT he don't know PATH of **hboost/predef**. Try to add **C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.5.467\toolkit\include\** to your additional include project directory

Comment: C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.5.467\toolkit\include\hboost\predef\os   there is no **cygwin.h** file in this path

Comment: Ok, in this case, you probably have (in addition to the configuration problem) a problem installing the cygwin extensions.

Comment: and there's no **cygwin.h** file even inside cygwin installed directory